# How to apply a textured gold leaf color effect for a font with gradual lighter effect

Tags: css, textures, adobe-illustrator

How can I archive the style effects for the textured gold leaf color of the font that gradually gets lighter from left to right? I have the font and the background image and I want to reconstruct this image, ideally using CSS effects (applying a class to a block element). If that's not possible, than using Adobe Illustrator or something alike. I have no idea where to start.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is use multiple [backgrounds/background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_backgrounds_and_borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) on your text to get the effect that you want.

I think I was able to create a solution using `background`, `background-blend-mode`, and `background-clip: text`.

You'll have to tweak the linear-gradient to get the correct look from your design but this should be the right idea.

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: transparent;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4rem;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618352357270-ef40d25bcef8?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2080&q=80) center/cover no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0), #fff 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) center/cover no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: ok, that goes in the right direction, thank you. I'll try to work with that and see were it leads.